# how to grep utc date using regular expression in shell

Tags: regex, grep

Hi can anyone suggest how to grep UTC DateTime in Linux?

I'm trying the below syntax but not working.

```
utcdate=$(grep '\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])T(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\dZ' filename)
```

date format : 2021-06-22T16:15:23Z

Comment: `grep` doesn’t (usually) understand `\d`.

Comment: `utcdate=$(grep -oP '\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])T(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\dZ' filename | head -1)`

Comment: Please do share samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: @kirank : You have instructed `grep` to use _basic regular expressions_. If you do this, you have to restrict yourself to these.  See the section titled _Matcher Selection_ in the grep _man-page_.

Comment: To nitpick: that's not a "UTC" date, that's an ISO 8601 standard date time format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is by adding `-oP` options and append `| head -1` to the pattern:

```sh
utcdate=$(grep -oP '\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])T(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\dZ' filename | head -1)
```

The `o` option will output the matched substring only, `P` will allow the PCRE regex syntax and `| head -1` to ensure you get a single match.

A POSIX pattern is also possible:

```sh
utcdate=$(grep -oE '[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]Z' filename | head -1)
```

where

- All `(?:` are replaced with `(` as the non-capturing groups are not supported by POSIX ERE
- `\d` replaced with `[0-9]` (as `\d` is not supported by POSIX regex).

If you escape all `(`, `)`, `{` and `}`, you can remove `E` as this expression will become POSIX BRE compliant, but that "escaping hell" looks ugly, IMHO.

Comment: On some platforms you can use `-m 1` to avoid the extra pipe to `head` but I believe this isn't portable. MacOS `grep` interprets `-m 1` with `-o` to restrict matches to the first matching line, but will still print multiple matches.

Comment: @tripleee This is why I prefer `head -1` and used it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you could try following code. This will give multiple occurrences of date in a single line too.

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]Z' 'RT{print RT}' Input_file
```

Above will print all occurrences of dates in whole Input_file in case you want to print only very first match then try following.

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]Z' 'RT{print RT;exit}' Input_file
```

***Explanation of regex:***

```
[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-       ##matching 4 digits followed by - matching 0 1 to 9 OR 1 OR 0 to 2 here.
([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T            ##matching 1 to 2 0 to 9 OR 3 0 or 1 here followed by T.
([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]  ##match 0 or 1 OR match 2 followed by 0 to 3 colon 0 to 5 followed by 0 to 9.
:[0-5][0-9]Z                    ##matching colon 0 to 5 followed by 0 to 9 followed by Z.
```